# unable to get list value in spring 3.0 mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

my **regForm.jsp** is:

```
    <form:form action="save.html">
    form:label path="name">Name *</form:label>
    <form:input path="name" />
    <form:label path="hobbies">Hobbies *<br />use (ctrl) botton to multiple select </form:label>
    <form:select path="hobbies" id="hobbies" multiple="true"
                                items="${hobList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="hobbyName">
    </form:select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addFormValidate()" />
    </form>
```

My **Beans**

```
public class User {
    private int id;     
    priavte List<Hobby> hobbies;
    //setter getter
}

public class Hobby {
    private int id;
    private String hobbyName;
    //setter getter
}
```

**myController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(
            @ModelAttribute("user") User user BindingResult result) {           
        System.out.println("name"+user.getName() );



    System.out.println(employee.getHobbies()); // getting null  
    //   usrDao.saveUser(user);
return new ModelAndView("redirect:add.html", model);
}
```

How could i get the value for **List from my form** so that i could get the value?
**What is wrong in my code? **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code----

```
package com.programsji.converter;

    import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

    import com.programsji.bo.Hobby;

    public class StringToHobbyConverter implements Converter<String, Hobby> {

        @Override
        public Hobby convert(String str) {
            // I Am Using Fix Hobbies Here, You Can Add Your Own Method to Get
            // Hobbies By ID
            Hobby hobby = null;
            if (str.equals("1")) {
                hobby = new Hobby(1, "First Hobby");
            } else if (str.equals("2")) {
                hobby = new Hobby(2, "Second Hobby");
            }
            return hobby;
        }

    }
```

To Register...

```
<annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
    <beans:bean id="conversionService"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="converters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="com.programsji.converter.StringToHobbyConverter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

It is working on my pc. if you need, I can send you source code.
About conversionService registration, you can view this example:

http://www.programsji.com/spring/converter

Answer (score 1):

You need an converter that converts the `Hobby id`, into an `hobby`.

@See: [Spring Reference, chapter 7.5 Spring 3 Type Conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert)

```
package org.springframework.core.convert.converter;

public class StringToHobbyConverter implements Converter<String, Hobby> {

    Hobby convert(String source) {
       return loadHobbyById(Integer.valueOf(source));
    }

}
```

Comment: how to convert it ? i don't more idea about conversion

Comment: and how would i map it to my controller ??

Comment: and how could covert method has body in interface ??? is it possible in interface case ???

Comment: @Ashish Ratan: start reading the reference documentation, I have added a link to the section in my answer.

Comment: @Ashish Ratan: The interface thing was a typo - I fixed the code. In the end it is the same answer that is proposed by `programsji.com`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the **User** model from:

```
public class User {
    private int id;     
    priavte List<Hobby> hobbies;
    //setter getter
}
```

to:

```
public class User {
    private int id;     
    priavte List<Integer> hobbies;
    //setter getter
}
```

Then you will get the list of hobby **ids** and you can loop through the list and create a new **Hobby** object for each id if required. Hope it helps!!

Comment: yeah it helps, and m doing the same thing so my code can work atleast. but this is not a good way i think.

Comment: Then may be converters can help as others have pointed out, but I have no experience with the converters.

Comment: same here.. no exp. with converters